# Does Symfony sfLucenePlugin support the symfony1.4 using propel as ORM?

Tags: symfony1

Does Symfony sfLucenePlugin support the symfony1.4 using propel as ORM?

Answer (score 0):

sfLucenePlugin integrates symfony and Zend Search Lucene to instantly add a search engine to your application. The plugin will auto-detect your ORM layer, but currently only supports Propel.